# I cannot be added as a developer or administrator to an app page

Tags: facebook, administrator, developer-tools

The current administrator to a Facebook app is trying to add me as a developer and/or administrator of the app. While typing in my email on Facebook, Facebook claims that I am not a Facebook user even though my account has been successfully verified by Facebook via mobile phone number. Any thoughts? Help!

Answer (score 2):

Add the admin as a friend.

I have admins as friends and it worked fine, and even people who have liked the page don't come up as suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your email is not added to your timeline, or you have not set the setting "Who can look you up using the email address or phone number you provided?" to "Everyone" or "Friends of Friends".

For more details, read the [`"Finding Friends & the Suggestions Feature"`](https://www.facebook.com/help/433894009984645/) section on the Facebook Help Center.

Note that adding as developer or administrator does not expect email, but a Facebook user name (as entered in the account). So, the current administrator can try typing `@Your Name` and that should find you (of course, depending on the Privacy settings I mentioned above).